# How to the increase keycload bearer access token time using curl?

Tags: keycloak

This is the curl command I am using to create a access token but that access token is getting expired after 60s

```
 curl   -d "client_id=admin-cli"  -d "username=myadminuser"   -d "password=myadminpass" -d "grant_type=password"   "http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/myrealmname/protocol/openid-connect/token"
```

Is there any way to increase the time of it while creating it using curl?

or by changing any realm settings in the admin console ui

Answer (score 0):

As default value, the `access_token` lifetime is set to 60 seconds, and the `refresh_token` lifetime is 30 minutes.

As described in the `OIDC` standard you can obtain a renewed `access_token` with a valid `refresh_token` whenever you want.

Beside that you can change the `access_token` lifespan in the realm settings:

> Realm `master` -> Realm Settings -> Tokens -> Access Token Lifespan

But keep in mind - it's recommended to use a short time period.

Answer (score 0):

In my case (Keycloak 15.0.2) I requested the token over the `master` realm. So my solution was:

1. Go to master realm
2. Click on clients
3. Click on `admin-cli` client
4. Scroll down to `Advanced Settings`, open it
5. Set your desired time in `Access Token Lifespan`
6. Save